# Repeat "report footer" every page in crystal report

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

Is it possible to repeat text in report footer section? My report has signatories in "Report Footer" section and I want that signatories to appear in every pages. Please help guys if you know the workaround on this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: if you need in every page then you need to palce the signatories in page footer

Comment: But if I place it in page footer, the signatories show at the bottom of the page.,What if there are few records to display? The page will be filled with white spaces.

Comment: Crystal reports will work this way... there will be only one report footer per report and there will be page footer for every page

Answer (score 0):

Try to use grouping it may help.
I had an issue where I needed to view the sum of every group of rows that start and end at a specific range and using perfected the solution.
So try to group the data in rows using any fake column then use group footer for your purpose.